# C++ ) Invalid operands to binary expression Error with Priority Queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, invalidoperationexception

I have a struct(A) and Priority Queue(PQ) at another struct(B).

This is struct A below :

```
struct Node{
int level;
int total;
std::vector<int> sequence;

void clear(){
    sequence.clear();
}

void init(){
    level = 0;
    total = 0;
    sequence.clear();
}

long subjectNumber(){
    return sequence.size();
}

bool isInSequence(int index){
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++){
        if(index == sequence.at(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}};
```

Nothing special right?

and I use priority queue of Node Objects like below :

```
    std::priority_queue<Node> pq;
```

But when I run the project I got an error :

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Node' and 'const Node')

I want to put **top priority for the total value of Node object**
How can I solve this problem?

```
UPDATED:
The picture is what I'm getting, at the project, there is no 'red'Line for me!
```

[image]

Comment: I found that I have to override method operator method... but when and how should I do that?

Comment: The problem in the code which is not shown here.

Comment: You cannot possibly be receiving this error when you run the project. You must be receiving it when you compile the project.

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the problem, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: It is not clear what line of posted code can correspond to the error message. -1 for editing out the single most relevant detail.

Comment: @AndyG What do you mean?

Comment: You don't have a comparator. Either operator<, or a functor. Have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Comment: It would be pleasure if you look my 'UPDATED!'

Comment: @LKM: Provide enough code so that I can attempt to compile it myself and get the same error you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to use `std::priority_queue<Node>`, you need a valid less than operator function for `Node`.

You can define the `operator<` overload as a member function or a non-member function.

**Member function overload**

```
struct Node{
   int level;
   int total;
   std::vector<int> sequence;

   void clear(){
      sequence.clear();
   }

   bool operator<(Node const& rhs) const { ... }
};
```

**Non-member function overload**

```
struct Node{
   int level;
   int total;
   std::vector<int> sequence;

   void clear(){
      sequence.clear();
   }

};

bool operator<(Node const& lhs, Node const& rhs) { ... }
```

**Using a `Compare` class**

You can also use a `Compare` class that provides the ability to compare two `Node` objects:

```
struct NodeCompare
{
    bool operator()(Node const& lhs, Node const& rhs) { ... }
};
```

and use it to construct `std::priority_queue` object.

```
using MyQueue = std::priority_queue<Node, NodeCompare>;
MyQueue queue;
```

Comment: @R Sahu brother, what you told me is working but not perfectly I think the overloaded method operator is just covering comparison of just 'two' Node objects... Isn't it problem? There are often exceptions found in my program

Comment: @LKM, that is the core functionality needed by `priority_queue`. It's hard telling what could be the cause of the exceptions being thrown. Please create another question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

[`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) requires that the element type provides an overloaded `operator<` (or a comparator via the `Compare` template argument):

```
bool operator<(const Node& lhs, const Node &rhs) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you @vitaut ! But where and how could I do that?

Comment: You can overload the `operator<` function as a member function or a non-member function.

Comment: @RSahu Should I overload at structA ( == struct Node)?

Comment: @RSahu Thank you but R, when I coded that method in struct Node, I got an error : **Overloaded 'operator<' must be a binary operator(has 3 parameters)**

Comment: @LKM, when it is a member overload, you'll have to use `bool operator<(const Node& rhs) const;`. When it's a non-member overload, you'll have to use the syntax used in the answer.